# Why Go doesn't report compile error when passing a pointer to function as value?

Tags: function, pointers, go, parameters

I suppose if I try to pass a pointer to a function, then this function declaration should also receive a pointer? Not sure, I tried this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type I interface {
    Get() int
    Set(int)
}

type S struct {
    Age int
}
func (s S) Get() int {
    return s.Age
}
func (s *S) Set(age int) {
    s.Age = age
}
func f(i I) {
    i.Set(10)
    fmt.Println(i.Get())
}
func main() {
    s := S{}
    f(&s) //4
    fmt.Println(s.Get())
}
```

It prints

```
10
10
```

We see that function of f is

```
func f(i I)
```

I'm not sure if this is a "pass by value" declaration, if by value, then "i" shouldn't be changed outside function "f" right, which is a copy inside "f".

So which point did I get wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [colminator's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58687600/1256452), but, for a rather imperfect analogy to straight C code, imagine that:

```
var x interface{ ... } // fill in the `...` part with functions
```

—or in this case, declaring `i I` to make `i` have the interface type you defined—is like declaring a C `struct` with two members, one to hold a type, and one to hold a value of that type:

```
struct I {
    struct type_info *type;
    union {
        void *p;
        int i;
        double d;
        // add more types if/as needed here
    } u;
};
struct I i;
```

The compiler fills in the `i.type` slot when you pass `&s` to `i`, and fills in `i.u.p` to point to the object `s`.<sup>1</sup>

When you invoke `i.Set(10)`, the Go compiler turns this into the equivalent of:

```
(*__lookup_func(i, "Set"))(i.u.p)
```

where `__lookup_func` finds the actual `func (s *S) Set(age int)` and an excessive amount of magic discovers that it should pass the pointer to `s` (from `i.u.p`) to that setter function.<sup>2</sup>

The fact that a variable of some interface types has these two slots—the "type" part, and the union-like part that holds the current value—is the real secret sauce here.  You can use a type-assertion:

```
v, ok := i.(int)
```

or a type-switch:

```
switch v := i.(type) {
case int: // code where `v` is `var v int`
case float64: // code where `v` is `var v float64` ...
// add more cases as desired
}
```

to check the type slot while also copying the value slot to a new variable `v`.<sup>3</sup>

Note that an `interface` variable compares equal to `nil` *if and only if **both** slots* (`i.type` and `i.u`) are nil.  The thing that trips people up all the time is that if you initialize an `interface` value from some non-interface type, its `type` slot is no longer nil, and the test:

```
if i == nil { // handle the case ...
```

doesn't work, *even if the value slot* (`i.u.p` in our analogy here) *is* `nil`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I show this as a union of several C types, but don't include `struct` types.  In fact, the size of the second slot of an `interface` value is not something the compiler makes any promises about, though in current compilers, it's just 8 bytes like any other pointer.  If whatever value type you have is too big for the actual underlying implementation, though, the compiler inserts an allocation: the value goes into some additional memory, and the union's pointer field is set to point the value.

The compiler checks, at compile time, that the type of the *actual* value you're stuffing into some interface, fits into that interface.  An interface type has a list of functions that it must support.  If the underlying type has those functions, the assignment is OK (and the compiler knows to build the appropriate vtable-like data mentioned in footnote 2).  If the underlying type is missing some function(s), you get a compile-time error.  So you're definitely guaranteed that a later function-lookup on the interface variable will always succeed.

<sup>2</sup>The lookup is faster than the implied string lookup here as `Set` has an integer code value that the compiler assigned at compile time to that particular interface type, and the internal `struct type_info` stuff has various fast lookup tables, somewhat akin to C++ vtables, to help it out as well.

The "excessive amount of magic" is greatly reduced in most cases to just "put the right parameter in the right argument register or stack location": it's harmless to copy extra bytes that the callee never reads.  If integer vs floating-point requires different argument registers, though, it gets a little tricky, and I'm not sure what current Go compilers actually do here.

<sup>3</sup>In the `v, ok := i.(int)` form, if the type slot *doesn't* hold `int`, `v` is set to zero, and `ok` is set to `false`.  This holds regardless of the actual type: *all* types have a default zero value, and `v` becomes a zero-value of the type you gave.

Answer (score 2):

`f(&s)` is passing the pointer address of `s` by value - just like any other go function call. The fact that the function takes an interface parameter does not change this fact.

Now regarding how the interface works: an interface value contains 2 items: the value & the underlying type. The value in this case is the pointer to the struct. The type verifies that `s` satisfies the interface - because it implements the Get/Set function signatures.

Since a pointer receiver of a method can alter the receiver's data fields - the `&s` can be altered by the `Set` method. And by extension, calling `f(&s)` - which invokes Set - thus also alters the struct `s`'s state.

P.S. this behavior is crucial for most of the go standard library. Many packages e.g. `http` rely on the `io.Reader` & `io.Writer` interfaces. Functions & methods that accept values that implement these interfaces, rely on the underlying concrete types changing state, reading network ports, flushing caches etc. to work - all the while not burdening the caller with these internal side effects.